# Too many "java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)" when dump thread on Java game server by Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, state

I am running a Socket Game Server base on Netty framework. This time, the server have a serious problem: CPU usage 0% and didn't accept anymore connection suddenly.

The average CCU is about 100

I dump the java thread and realize that there are too many thread with state

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
```

Is this normal with Netty framework or I do some stupid ?

Here is my [dump file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55451598/dump_jstack.txt)

Comment: I see many idle thread in your thread pool

Comment: Looks fine. A webserver has many idle threads, they wait for a new connection to process - you can see that the threads are blocked on a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: What's your CPU process count? netty will use processCount*2 for IO thread defualt.

Comment: @Spring.Rush i read in [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) that `WAITING` is `A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.` so I think the Thread is waiting by synchronize

Comment: @Spring.Rush at first, I leave it default. After running several weeks, I realize that the server response has some latency and now I set up like that `new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 32)`